# Caldroid: How to modify size and position

Tags: android, caldroid

I am trying to include Caldroid calendar in my activity. I want that the calendar ocuppy 3/4 of the screen like this:

[image]

But it always shows at the top of the screen.

This is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/opciones"
        android:layout_width="299dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/calendar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is how i attach the caldroid:

```
  FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        t.replace(R.id.calendar1, caldroidFragment);
        t.commit();
```

I search it in StackOverFlow but i dont find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved it implementing my own custom_cell and modify the padding_bottom to increase the cell size.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_cell"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="68dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

It is one solution but maybe not the most elegant.

Answer (score -1):

there are two way for this :

**first way :**
use `android:layout_weight=""` instead static size for `LinearLayout`

for example :

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/parentLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/options"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/calendar1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

---

**Second Way :**
using `PercentLayout` (work with percentage and maybe Clearer)

1. add `Percent` library to your app by adding this line to  gradle dependency:

   ```
    dependencies {
   ...
   compile 'com.android.support:percent:24.1.2' //or any other versions
   ...
   }
   ```
2. in `XML layout` :

   ```
       <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/options"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           app:layout_widthPercent="30%"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:orientation="horizontal">
       </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_toRightOf="@id/options"
           android:id="@+id/calendar1"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           app:layout_widthPercent="70%"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:orientation="horizontal">
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

notice that :

- add `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to first parent of layout
- `android:layout_toRightOf` specify the second view(`layout_below` is possible too)

Comment: it doesnt work for me. the caldroid keep his size. it only modify his width but not his height.

Comment: @garciam202 for height you should use `app:layout_heightPercent="int%"`